# Is it possible to create a generic method or class that one can use to create "new" instances of any class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Normally, if I have a `Foo`, or a `Bar`, I would do something like:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();

Bar* bar = new Bar(2,3,5);
```

Is there a way using templates or macros, that I can construct a function, such that I can do something like:

```
Foo* foo = MyAwesomeFunc(Foo);
Bar* bar = MyAwesomeFunc(Bar,2,3,5);
```

> The actual method signature of `MyAwesomeFunc` is not important to me.

`Foo` and `Bar` need not be related in any possible way, and may have completely different constructors. Additionally, I may want to support any number of classes in the future without having to actually modify the code of `MyAwesomeFunc`

Is this possible ? A simple way would be to have both `Foo` and `Bar` inherit from some type, say `Baz`, and have overloaded methods return a `Baz`, which you cast back to `Foo` or `Bar`...

```
Baz* MyAwesomeFunc(){
    return new Foo();
}

Baz* MyAwesomeFunc(int a,int b,int c){
    return new Bar(a,b,c);
}
```

But the problems here is you would have to write:

1. a method for each class supported
2. and for each kind of constructor signature.

> The goal, is to write a single class, method, or macro, where we can
>   call one function (and pass it any arguments), but call the right
>   constructor of the passed in object. Is this possible ?

**The purpose of this question is to simply explore if it is possible to do something like this in C++. Please do not bring up shared pointers, unique pointers, the pitfalls of using new, as that is off topic.**

EDIT: I would like to use only the STL, and avoid using things like Boost....

Comment: See `boost::factory`

Comment: @Ari0nhh Thanks Ari - any way to do this easily without using Boost ?

Comment: Pre C++11, "Perfect Forwarding" and "Variadic Templates" didnt exist. `Boost` supplied the community with the tools to make stupidly powerful code and `boost::factory` was the defacto factory which has been superceeded by perfect forwarding and variadic templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++11 you can do it with [variadic template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [perfect forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward). E.g. write a template function, which perfect forwards its parameters to the constructor of the object with type specified by template parameter.

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
T* MyAwesomeFunc(Ts&&... params){
    return new T(std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
}
```

Then use it as

```
Foo* foo = MyAwesomeFunc<Foo>();
Bar* bar = MyAwesomeFunc<Bar>(2,3,5);
```

Comment: What happens if you try to create a Bar, without all the required arguments ?

Comment: You can use `std::is_constructible` from `type_traits`. See my answer.

Comment: @John, Compiler error. It won't look perfect from the outside, but there are ways to fix that (concepts, and emulation thereof).

Comment: @John If the arguments provided don't match the constructor of the object, then you'll get a compiler error; it's same as when you write `new Bar(something);`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use templates and C++11's "Perfect Forwarding":

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T* createNew(Args&&... args)
{
  static_assert(std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value, "T is not constructible with these arguments");
  return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Alternatively, you could check out C++11's `std::make_unique` and "Smart Pointers" [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: If there will be a compiler error, then why use std::is_constructible ?

Comment: Because you can set your own message and it wont be lost in horrible compiler errors.